To have something in one's possession
Saying I have something in my possession, in this case, 3 pieces of luggage. I have three possible verbs:

みっつ荷物が持ちます。
みっつ荷物が有します。
みっつ荷物があります。

Which one is best?
Thanks,
Robert

Minor nitpick: I think the first two options use transitive verbs, so if I'm not mistaken you'd want to use を instead of が.

Also, you need to either say 「みっつの荷物」, or put みっつ after the が.

Only the third sentence is correct.

みっつ荷物が持ちます。
The luggage holds three (pieces of something).
みっつ荷物が有します。
The luggage possesses three (pieces of something).
✅ みっつ荷物があります。
✅ There are three pieces of luggage.

Sentence 1 uses a wrong particle and a wrong verb. が is a subject marker, not an object marker. 持つ is a transitive verb that describes a physical action of picking up, holding and carrying something. For example, a porter can 持つ your luggage without owing it.
Sentence 2 also uses a wrong particle, and the use of 有する is questionable. 有する is a stiff verb used mainly in legal or technical contexts.
Sentence 3 is already fine, but the standard word order is 荷物がみっつあります.
